# show div when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: jquery

I have made the checkbox and if this is unchecked show div element.

So I tried

```js
$('.switch-info').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('.txt-switch-info').hide():$('.txt-switch-info').show();  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="switch1">
  <em class="txt-switch1">ON</em>  <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" value="" class="switch-info" checked>
</label>
<span class="txt-switch-info" style="display: none;">show this div when unchecked</span>
```

This works fine.

But when I use this multi times of checkbox, the showing DIV is not working well. 
Like this

```
<label for="switch1">
      <em class="txt-switch1">ON</em>  <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" value="" class="switch-info" checked>
    </label>
    <span class="txt-switch-info" style="display: none;">show this div when unchecked</span>

<label for="switch2">
      <em class="txt-switch1">ON</em>  <input type="checkbox" id="switch2" value="" class="switch-info" checked>
    </label>
    <span class="txt-switch-info" style="display: none;">show this div when unchecked</span>

<label for="switch3">
      <em class="txt-switch1">ON</em>  <input type="checkbox" id="switch3" value="" class="switch-info" checked>
    </label>
    <span class="txt-switch-info" style="display: none;">show this div when unchecked</span>
```

What should I fix the code?  Please help.

Comment: It is because `$(class).hide()` and `$(class).show()` applies to each and every element of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need restrucute your HTML to have a wrapper `div` for each checbox and then use the `$(this)` to get the checkbox inside the wrapper to show/hide.

```js
$('.switch-info').click(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).closest('div').find('.txt-switch-info').hide();
  } else {
    $(this).closest('div').find('.txt-switch-info').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label for="switch1">
  <em class="txt-switch1">ON</em>  <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" value="" class="switch-info" checked>
</label>
  <span class="txt-switch-info" style="display: none;">show this div when unchecked</span>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="switch1">
  <em class="txt-switch1">ON</em>  <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" value="" class="switch-info" checked>
</label>
  <span class="txt-switch-info" style="display: none;">show this div when unchecked</span>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="switch1">
  <em class="txt-switch1">ON</em>  <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" value="" class="switch-info" checked>
</label>
  <span class="txt-switch-info" style="display: none;">show this div when unchecked</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM traversal functions relative to `$(this)`. Also, you can use `.toggle()` instead of writing your own conditional.

```js
$(".switch-info").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next().toggle(!this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="switch1">
      <em class="txt-switch1">ON</em>  <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" value="" class="switch-info" checked>
</label>
<span class="txt-switch-info" style="display: none;">show this div when unchecked</span>

<label for="switch2">
      <em class="txt-switch1">ON</em>  <input type="checkbox" id="switch2" value="" class="switch-info" checked>
</label>
<span class="txt-switch-info" style="display: none;">show this div when unchecked</span>

<label for="switch3">
      <em class="txt-switch1">ON</em>  <input type="checkbox" id="switch3" value="" class="switch-info" checked>
</label>
<span class="txt-switch-info" style="display: none;">show this div when unchecked</span>
```

Comment: Cool nice solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Use `.parent().next`

```js
$('.switch-info').click(function() {
  this.checked ? $(this).parent().next('.txt-switch-info').hide() : $(this).parent().next('.txt-switch-info').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="switch1">
  <em class="txt-switch1">ON</em>  <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" value="" class="switch-info" checked>
</label>
<span class="txt-switch-info" style="display: none;">show this div when unchecked</span>

<label for="switch2">
  <em class="txt-switch2">ON</em>  <input type="checkbox" id="switch2" value="" class="switch-info" checked>
</label>
<span class="txt-switch-info" style="display: none;">show this div when unchecked</span>
```